# how to publish and discover a java web service

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws, uddi, juddi

I am new to developing web services using java. I have an academic project where I need to do dynamic service composition. For that I can't directly create a service-client for a particular service because if I do so then that client will call that particular service only. Client need to search various web services and then out of those services select any one at run time and also call that service at run time.

I was able to develop the web service(JAX-WS) using Eclipse(indigo), I also created the client for that web service and every thing is working fine. Now my problem is that while creating the client I am hard coding the client to call that particular web service only(since I am creating the client using the WSDL file of the service). However I actually need to call any one of the searched service, but for that I need to publish the  service some where then discover it and then call it.

I tried publishing the service to juddiv3. But on juddiv3 I could only publish the sample service supplied with the juddiv3. When I try to publish service created by me then it is not getting displayed in the group of published services.

Is there any other UDDI server which I could install on my local machine and then publish and discover the service from that. Also I was not able to figure out how to create a client that will modify itself at run time to call any one service out of various searched services.

Kindly provide the necessary steps and code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jUDDI (http://juddi.apache.org/ ).

**juddi** is based on **UDDI v2.0, v 3.0** .

Here, you can publish as well as discover your web service.

For integration, you have to make some application which integrates with **jUDDI**.

But I think for your academic project, and **for your purpose**, jUDDI is best suitable! ( :) )

Comment: As the asker mentions he tried this, perhaps you could add a small sample which works?

Answer (score 0):

jUDDI has a boat load of examples in the source code trunk. You may want to check them out. It's difficult to guess what the problem is from the little information you've provided. Consider contacting the jUDDI team for further assistance. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/. There's also additional document for working with UDDI in the jUDDI user's guide, which is at the jUDDI web site

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly publish on jUDDI. You need to create publisher entities in jUDDI server also. You'll find Rename4Sales and Rename4Marketing examples in 'Classes' folder in the standalone server's juddi application. Use these XMLs as your basis and create your own entity. You also need to configure the server's login credentials.

I suggest you follow the tutorials on jUDDI blog.